# How is ssh2 installed for PHP 7.4 on Rocky Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh2

I recently upgraded to Rocky. I am getting an error on a PHP SSH command that has worked for years.  Everything I try fails for various reasons.  I need to ssh from PHP.  At this point I am not particular about the method used. This is the code used for ssh connections:

```
$ssh = ssh2_connect($ssh_domain);
if( ssh2_auth_password($ssh_user, $ssh_password) ) 
    {
      // send the command
    }
```

but I get this error on the connect line:

```
Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()
```

I installed with

```
yum install libssh2-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:00 ago on Wed 03 Aug 2022 12:50:28 PM EDT.
Dependencies resolved.
====================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                Architecture                    Version                                 Repository                     Size
====================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 libssh2-devel                          x86_64                          1.9.0-5.el8                             epel                           68 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 68 k
Installed size: 288 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
libssh2-devel-1.9.0-5.el8.x86_64.rpm                                                                                309 kB/s |  68 kB     00:00
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                               141 kB/s |  68 kB     00:00
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                            1/1
  Installing       : libssh2-devel-1.9.0-5.el8.x86_64                                                                                           1/1
  Running scriptlet: libssh2-devel-1.9.0-5.el8.x86_64                                                                                           1/1
  Verifying        : libssh2-devel-1.9.0-5.el8.x86_64                                                                                           1/1

Installed:
  libssh2-devel-1.9.0-5.el8.x86_64

Complete!
```

and then I restarted apache.

What am I doing wrong?  Did I install the wrong package?  Maybe I need to install something else?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Even if this is off-topic here, as it is not related to programming: did you install the proper PHP extension, **and** enable it?

Comment: I don’t understand how this is not programming related. I’ve been using StackOverflow for over 12 years and I’ve seen many questions regarding how to configure programming environments, including PHP.  Anyway, that is what I am asking, what things do I need to do to ensure everything is enabled.

Comment: Pretty simple: installing a package on any server is not related to programming. serverfault.com is better suited for such questions